# Unable to set json string to TextView in onPostExecute in asyncTask

Tags: java, json, android-asynctask

The problem that I'm facing right now is I simply want to set the string data from a json array in onPostExecute(). I skeemed through many tutorials on it, however, I am unable to set the Text that resides in the MainActivity. I've added the sample code below . I wonder if the data is wrong .

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonobject) {
        try {
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("grape");
            outerjson = jsonarray;
            String ids = jsonobject.optString("id");
            String tpes = jsonobject.optString("type");


            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                String str = "";}

            // Step 3.
            map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // this is the last step 4.
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json = null;
                    json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    map1.put("id", json.getString("id"));
                    map1.put("type", json.getString("type"));

                }

                result.setText(jsonarray.toString());


                ///set the json in here
            }catch (JSONException e) {}
        } catch (JSONException e) {}
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: post your `jsonobject`, show us the structure of the JSON data.

Comment: This is the type of json data , I want to get the type from this data.  {"grape":[{"id":"4","type":"2\u7b49"}],"result":"OK"}

Comment: Your codes look like a mess. Do you know what do you want exactly?

Comment: It is totally a mess, however, there is a reason to this....

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information, but I will try:

1. Make your code cleaner by using a container entity: `MyData data = gson.fromJson(jsonobject, MyData.class)`.
2. Do not ignore exceptions
3. Make sure you are calling `result.setText(string);` within a main UI thread

Follow these 3 steps and, find the error, you will.